# 4.10 PlugIn With NuGet Package Reference Does Not Deploy Correctly

Tags: c#, nuget, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.1

I have a simple nopCommerce 4.10 plugin which when deployed and loaded cannot locate assemblies referenced via a Nuget package.

> Exception: Plugin 'my plugin'. Could not load file or assembly
>   'IdentityServer4, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I copy the nuget package's assembly directly into the project and treat it as content and deploy the assembly is found and loaded however this is hacky and cannot be the way this is supposed to work.

I can see the Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square plugin uses RestSharp however itself does not reference the Nuget package but instead as a copy of the assembly in the root of the plugin directory, just as I did in my workaround.

So the question is - how are nuget packages referenced within a plugin supposed to be deployed and resolved?

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

My last solution is using `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` in plugin.csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

it will copy all references, not only NuGet packages, plugin's artifact will be quite big, but it works.

I'm trying to find better way, but no luck yet.

Comment: This is the preferred solution at the moment. If you look at the definition of built-in plugins (in the csproj) you'll find this comment above <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>: 

Set this parameter to true to get the dlls copied from the NuGet cache to the output of your project. You need to set this parameter to true if your plugin has a nuget package to ensure that the dlls copied from the NuGet cache to the output of your project